# How to get the radical solution of $\sin\frac{π}{7}$ whose outer shell is the cubic root?

Tags: trigonometry

The traditional solution is to solve the minimum polynomial

$$
\begin{aligned}
64 x^6-112 x^4+56 x^2-7 &= 0\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Let us use Cardano's Method, Take $t=4 x^2-\dfrac{7}{3}$, then:

$$
t^3-\frac{7 t}{3}+\frac{7}{27} = 0
$$

which solves t:

$$
t = \sqrt[3]{-\frac{7}{2}+\frac{21 i \sqrt{3}}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{-\frac{7}{2}-\frac{21 i \sqrt{3}}{2} }
$$

Choose the appropriate branch, the solution obtained is:

$$
\sin\frac{\pi}{7}=\sqrt{\frac{7}{12}-\frac{1}{24} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{-\frac{7}{2}+\frac{21 i \sqrt{3}}{2}}-\frac{1}{24} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{-\frac{7}{2}-\frac{21 i \sqrt{3}}{2}}}
$$

The characteristic is that the quadratic root is set into the cubic root and then the quadratic root is set into.

---

But I found another version of the solution recorded in a book.

$$
\sin\frac{\pi}{7}=-\frac{\sqrt{7}}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{\frac{13\sqrt{7}+3\sqrt{21}i}{2}}+\frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{\frac{13\sqrt{7}-3\sqrt{21}i}{2}}\\
$$

This solution is a cubic root of a quadratic root

It is verified that the minimum polynomial is also

$$
64 x^6-112 x^4+56 x^2-7
$$

How was this kind of solution obtained?

---

Note that this question is different from [Exact values of cos(2π/7)
and sin(2π/7)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38414/exact-values-of-cos2-pi-7-and-sin2-pi-7), do not merge directly.

That answer also the traditional solution.

Comment: What happened when you tried to use Cardano's Method for Cubic Equations, as discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), to answer your question?  Please edit your posting to show your work.