# How do I compute the eleventh roots of unity algebraically, expressed with only square roots and fifth roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, roots-of-unity

I was able to reduce the problem to solving the quintic equation $$x^5+x^4-4x^3-3x^2+3x+1=0,$$ which seems to be the minimal polynomial of $2\cos(2\pi/11)=e^{2\pi i/11}+e^{-2\pi i/11}$. But I couldn't find a method to go further with my calculation. I haven't studied Galois theory, although I know some basic field theory.

Comment: I'm not quite certain want you want. Galois theory (with the addition of results by Kummer) does say that if $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11},e^{2\pi i/5})$, then there exists an element $z\in K$ such that $e^{2\pi i/11}\in K(\root5\of z)$, enabling us to write $e^{2\pi i/11}$ in terms of $\sqrt{-11}$, $e^{2\pi i/5}$ and $\root5\of z$, which is probably what you are looking for. But it would take a bit of my time to figure out $z$ and the sought after expression.

Comment: Your experience on the site will probably improve, if you take a look at [our abridged guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619). You may have noticed that some reviewers already voted to put your question on hold for it is not quite up to the expected standards. I'm sure you can do a better job, and in that link others have collected pointers about what's expected.

Comment: Ok. Put such pieces of information into the question body (like I just did). That way you make a more convincing case. It's just one of the "charms" of how this site works :-). Thinking a bit more about the actual question. Kummer's method also tells how to get that cosine in terms of a fifth root of some element of the cyclotomic field $\Bbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/5})$. So we can possibly leave out $\sqrt{-11}$. But I gotta work now. We have many users capable of helping you. If not, I may come back to this later.

Comment: What is the source of the problem?

Comment: @DS I was able to calculate the seventh roots of unity by reducing the problem to solving the cubic equation $x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1 = 0$, however I couldn't do the same trick with the eleventh roots as I don't know how to solve quintic equations.

Comment: Since there is no general method for quintics

Comment: I think I have seen a similar question, but I'm neither sure nor can I find it.

Comment: @DS My recollection is similar. I thought I had answered a similar question about $e^{2\pi i/7}$, but couldn't find it. May be I only answered in a comment as I couldn't be arsed to do the calculation to the end :-)

Comment: [An earlier thread on the seventh root of unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38414/11619).

Comment: [Earlier stuff about the eleventh root](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4468729/11619)

Comment: Abel first and Galois after etc, etc..... Maybe your particular quintic admits the formula you desire but why? Meanwhile follow reading Quora.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Radical representation of $\cos\frac {2\pi}{11}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4468729/radical-representation-of-cos-frac-2-pi11)

Comment: @BenjaminWang Not much, I don't understand the method of solution.